# J2EE Servlet request forwarding (Oracle ATG)

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, httprequest, atg-dynamo

I am working on ATG which is an oracle product. The question I have is that if I receive a HTTPRequest from client(browser). The j2EE server forwards the request to ATG which creates a custom dynamohttpRequest. At this stage i want to change context and call the server again. I cant do it with the dynamoHttpRequest.

So I am planning to generate a new request or forward the request to a service as httpRequest. How can I generate a new request or forward the request to the same server from a servlet. How would that impact session for the client. Will Request forwarding impact the client session.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you cant do with DynamoHttpRequest, but you can add your own Servlet in the RequestHandlingPipeline (/atg/dynamo/servlet/dafpipeline/DynamoHandler)

check this out : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s0807customizingarequesthandlingpipel01.html